# What's the class used by Mule to send JMS Message (Endpoint)

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, mule

I'm trying to send a message with the existing Mule code. Already made some code but for some reason and as far as i've read there's kinda an axis "bug".

Used JMSEndpoint to then call the "call" method to send the message and wait for a response. This is my code:

```
        String payload = eventContext.getMessage().getPayloadAsString();
        JmsConnector amqConnector = (JmsConnector) eventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupConnector("Active_MQ");
        JMSVendorAdapter adapter = JMSVendorAdapterFactory.getJMSVendorAdapter();
        QueueConnector connector = new QueueConnector(amqConnector.getConnectionFactory(), 1, 1, 2000, 2000, 60000, true, null, null, null, adapter, null);

        Connection connection = connector.getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("ExampleQueue");
        JMSEndpoint endpoint = connector.createEndpoint(queue);
        connector.start();

//      Byte byteMessage = new Byte(payload);
//      BytesMessage mess = session.createBytesMessage();
//      mess.writeByte(byteMessage);

        byte[] response = endpoint.call(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"), 10000);

        return response.toString();
```

The method itself is asking for a byte[] so i'm giving it a byte[] with UTF-8 charset.
But its throwing this error:

```
org.apache.axis.transport.jms.InvokeException: Error: unexpected message type received - expected BytesMessage
```

In the JMSConnector class, it's failing in this block:

```
BytesMessage response = null;
                try {
                    response = (BytesMessage)subscriber.receive(timeout);
                } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
                    throw new InvokeException
                            ("Error: unexpected message type received - expected BytesMessage");
                }
```

There was an opened ticket regarding this issue, which they called to be a "bug"??? So its kinda a ClassCastException being thrown! can't believe this has been made! Is there a way to solve this??? How does Mule do it then??

How can I achieve sending JMS Messages to a Queue like Mule does in its component?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the connector manually for any particular reason? I think the best would be to use MuleClient.send (or dispatch if you have an asynchronous call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mule dispatches messages to JMS destinations using the [org.mule.transport.jms.JmsMessageDispatcher](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/transport/jms/JmsMessageDispatcher.html)

Comment: As Seba said, the easiest way to use the dispatcher is via the MuleClient.

Comment: Yeah, tried using the JmsMessageDispatcher but no parameter to add a queue name or something.

Comment: Now guys, does Mule opens and closes a connection every time it passes through this JMS Component? or leaves it opened?

Comment: JmsMessageDispatcher uses a single Connection provided by the JmsConnector it depends from.

Comment: OHhh great! so this can be implemented without any problem by using dynamic queue names! :) great!!! thanks david